# Issue in start of vncserver through cronjob

Tags: cron, centos7, redhat, vnc, vnc-server

Following script I use to start vnc,

```sh
cd $HOME; vncserver -kill :12 
cd $HOME; vncserver :12 -geometry 1280x1024 -name myvnc --alwaysshared
```

It works when I run from terminal, but It gives error when run from cronjob

Screenshot of vnc when start from cron

[image]

Machine configuration

```
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

Machine was up for last 141 days, after reboot of machine the above issue gets resolved. Can any one tell me how to figure out what cause this issue to arise?

Update:
Still, issues arise within every 3-4 days after reboot.

Comment: Maybe works when you add `DISPLAY=:12` near the top of your crontab?

Comment: @Roadowl not worked.

Comment: "It gives error when run from cronjob" << can you please describe _which_ error?

Comment: @CherryDT No it does not.

Comment: Excuse me but how is "no it does not" answer the question "which error do you get"?

Comment: I didn't get any error in cron , process do run fine. It just output screen is not proper

Answer (score 1):

Suspects are as follows:

1. cron job user has been changed to/from root, and so $HOME has changed accordingly.
2. Try an "&& wait" to make sure the -kill has finished before issuing the next command.
3. Do you have a MAX sessions set?  Has it been reached? And X may be the issue.

Curious, what is the system response when you do the following?  Is the previous session still running?  Did the -kill command complete? Does it always?

```
vncserver -kill :12
ps -fU "$USER" | grep vnc  # or try:  ps -e | grep vnc
```

May I suggest the following to aid the debug process...

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$HOME" || exit 1         # a good habit, don't assume the landing.
echo "$HOME"                 # confirm that the value is what you expect.
vncserver -kill :12 && wait  # wait for the kill to complete before restarting
vncserver :12 -geometry 1289x1024 -name myvnc --alwaysshared
exit 0
```

Perhaps even better:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$HOME" || exit 1
if ! vncserver -kill :12 ; then
    vncserver :12 -geometry 1289x1024 -name myvnc --alwaysshared
else
    echo "Error: vncserver 12 Process NOT KILLED, $? "  # $? will give you the return/exit value of previous
fi
exit 0
```

Notes:

1. You didn't say what shell you are using but you can substitute #!/bin/bash  in place of #!/bin/sh
2. You didn't paste the error statement.

Answer (score 0):

Find a hack,

If I create vnc from root user then it works perfectly.

In cron you can add entry as below

```
su - myuser -c "cd $HOME; vncserver -kill :12; vncserver :12 -geometry 1280x1024 -name myvnc --alwaysshared "
```